# Merging specific files of a directory in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, merge

I have a directory C:/newdir/ It contains the following files with filenames :

```
s1_student1_file
t1_teacher2_file
hab_parent5_file
y1_professor_file 
bsa_assistant2_file
t1_student_file
nas_officer_file
ee1_newguy15_file
ee1_professor15_file
f1_student8_file
```

I want to merge the content of **s1_student1_file, t1_teacher2_file, t1_student_file, y1_professor_file,  ee1_newguy15_file, f1_student8_file, and ee1_professor15_file**  into a new file called all_file and deleting the files that have been merged from the directory I have to write a python code for this but cannot figure how.

Comment: are they text files?

Comment: yes they are text files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `glob` to list all the chosen text files in a chosen folder. Then, you can use a for-loop to loop over all the text file and write the content into another file:

```
from glob import glob

with open('all_file.txt','a') as f:
    for file in glob('s1*')+glob('t1*')+glob('y1*')+glob('ee1*'):
        with open(file+'txt','r') as r:
            f.write(r.read())
```

---

To remove the files afterwards:

```
from glob import glob
import os
with open('all_file.txt','a') as f:
    for file in glob('s1*')+glob('t1*')+glob('y1*')+glob('ee1*'):
        with open(file,'r') as r:
            f.write(r.read())
        os.remove(file)
```

Comment: sorry just one more thing, where in the code should I pass my directory as the argument?

Comment: You can change `glob('s1*')+glob('t1*')+glob('y1*')+glob('ee1*')` to `["C:/newdir/"+file for file in glob('s1*')+glob('t1*')+glob('y1*')+glob('ee1*')]`.

Comment: hi so how would I remove all the files that have been merged from the directory after merging them in the same code

Comment: Simply add `os.remove(file+'.txt')` right under the context manager..

Comment: hi the code is running and doesnt show any error but the files arent getting deleted

Comment: you said you wanted to remove them?

Comment: ya the files whose contents have been merged need to be removed from the directory after merging happens

Comment: could you also have a look at my other question

Comment: Just change the `f.write(r.read())` to `f.write(len(r.readlines()))`.

Comment: hi there was another modification required in which I had to merge the contents files from the second line of the files. For this I tried f.write(r.read()[1:]) but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Import shutil & pathlib libraries

You can install the libraries using this command –

pip install shutil

pip install pathlib

**Python Implementation**

```
import shutil 
from pathlib import Path 

firstfile = Path(r'C:\Users\Sohom\Desktop\A.txt') 
secondfile = Path(r'C:\Users\Sohom\Desktop\B.txt') 

newfile = input("Enter the name of the new file: ") 
print() 
print("The merged content of the 2 files will be in", newfile) 

with open(newfile, "wb") as wfd: 

for f in [firstfile, secondfile]: 
    with open(f, "rb") as fd: 
        shutil.copyfileobj(fd, wfd, 1024 * 1024 * 10) 

  print("\nThe content is merged successfully.!") 
 print("Do you want to view it ? (y / n): ") 

 check = input() 
 if check == 'n': 
exit() 
else: 
print() 
c = open(newfile, "r") 
print(c.read()) 
c.close()
```

......

Create Array of text files dynamically

Comment: Ann Zen's code does the job but I am having difficulty deleting the files that have to be merged from the directory after theyve been merged. Could you help me with that

Comment: import os
//Call this in loop using file array
    file_path = '/tmp/file.txt'
   os.remove(file_path)